# node server.js not responding error message

Tags: node.js, npm, terminal, server

I am working on a project that requires the use of node server.js file. The documentation for the project states to type in 'node server.js' in terminal to start the server, but when I do that I'm receiving an error cannot find module 'express'.

```
Error: Cannot find module 'express'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:455:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:403:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/.../Desktop/react/react-app-project/server.js:6:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
```

This is the code in server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

/*
this says: serve all the files in the src directory if they match the URL

For example, if the client requests http://server/css/app.css then the file in src/css/app.css will be served
But if the client requests http://server/step-2 then since there is no file by that name the middleware will call next()
*/
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/src'));

/* insert any app.get or app.post you need here. only if you do the advanced part */

/*
This says: for any path NOT served by the middleware above, send the file called index.html instead.
For example, if the client requests http://server/step-2 the server will send the file index.html. Then on the browser, React Router will load the appropriate component
*/
app.get('/*', function(request, response) {
  response.sendFile(__dirname + '/src/index.html');
});
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, function() {
  console.log('server started');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Cannot find module 'express'

the reason is that you didn't install express yet.

solution: `npm install express`